# Nested interfaces in Go

Tags: go, interface

I have an interface type in Go, which defines some methods, with their own nested interfaces. Something like this:

```
type Store interface {
    Pack(key string) interface {
        Put(r io.Reader) (int, error)
        io.Closer
    }
    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

Now, I define another interface, let's call it a Packer, which matches what the Pack method returns, like this:

```
type Packer interface {
    Put(r io.Reader) (int, error)
    io.Closer
}
```

I can then implement two kinds of Stores. One with a Pack method that returns a Packer, and another with a Pack that returns the explicit interface type:

```
func (s *storeTypeA) Pack(key string) Packer { ... }

func (s *storeTypeB) Pack(key string) interface {
    Put(r io.Reader) (int, error)
    io.Closer
} { ... }
```

There's only one problem now. `storeTypeA` doesn't actually conform to the Store interface anymore. If I try to pass it off as a Store, I get this error:

```
prog.go: cannot use storeTypeA literal (type *storeTypeA) as type Store in assignment:
    *storeTypeA does not implement Store (wrong type for Pack method)
        have Pack(string) Packer
        want Pack(string) interface { Close() error; Put(io.Reader) (int, error) }
```

What I don't understand though, is that the Packer interface *is* exactly equal to `interface { Close() error; Put(io.Reader) (int, error) }`. So why the error?

Any ideas how to work around this?

I guess the obvious thing would be to just not have the nested interfaces, but I'm kind of curious why this should be a problem. I'm doing it this way because I want to be able to define the interface *outside* of the package where I'm providing the Store itself.

Comment: `Packer` and `interface { Close() error; Put(io.Reader) (int, error) }` are 2 distinct types. Why do you need the anonymous interface in the Store definition?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/apbRi49DVH

Comment: @JimB: `type Packer interface { Close() error; Put(io.Reader) (int, error) }` looks the same as `interface { Close() error; Put(io.Reader) (int, error) }` to me? The one is just "anonymous" and the other has a name.

Comment: `type A int` and `type B int` look the same too, but are distinct types as far as Go's type system is concerned.

Comment: @Dave Just because it has the same definition doesn't make it the same interface. Thats a lot like saying that two instances of objects are the same if all their values are the same which they're not because they have different memory addresses.

Comment: There's quite a few questions to how you're writing Go. First off, why have the nested interface? Second, why not just import the package that supplies the `Packer` interface and embed the `Packer` interface in the `Store` interface? Third, why the anonymous interface to substitute the `Packer` interface?